# How can I share route structure for many components

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a component that has a number of children routes. Each child route is the same for a number of components (currently sitting at 6 and this is supposed to grow over time). In order to reduce duplication for each template (shown as `:template` route parameter) I made some common routes.

The child routes are as follows —

- `:template` - display dashboard
- `:template/:id` - view item details
- `:template/:id/update` - issue update on item
- `:template/new` - new item

With this approach I'm able to use a configuration object that maps each routes component type to a template and dynamically build my page.

My configuration object resembles this —

```
let TMPL_CONF = {
  'template_1': {
    'home': Template1HomeComponent,
    'id': Template1IdComponent,
    'update': Template1UpdateComponent,
    'new': Template1NewComponent,
  },
    'template_2': {
    'home': Template2HomeComponent,
    'id': Template2IdComponent,
    'update': Template2UpdateComponent,
    'new': Template2NewComponent,
  }
}
```

My question is, is there a better way of having a number of components (or templates in my case) share the same route structure without having me to define it manually each time a new template is added?

Comment: ES.next and TS already offer pretty much to keep it DRY. If you need to generate an object from several parameters, make a class.